# Connecting to swisscom dynamic storage dynstrg with dragondisk fails

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

No matter how I try and following the [guide](https://github.com/swisscom/dynstrg-howto#accessing-the-dynstrg-service-using-dragondisk), I can't access my storage with dragondisk.
Behind the swisscom firewall I get connection errors, outside I get "invalid response headers".
I'm using dragondisk 1.05 for OSX, accessHost, accessKey and sharedSecret as parameters as well as the setting "ssl/https".

Any hints?
- How can I enclose the error?
- What can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to work with Dragonfly for Mac. Using [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/) works.